# How to figure out why a specific dll version is expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have a large solution, containing several projects, all with different dependencies and Nuget packages.

For one specific project, when running, I eventually get an exception "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, [...]"

This happens when referencing one of our types for the first time, which doesn't have an obvious dependency on this specific assembly, but it is part of a large project that probably has one.

The thing is, We do have System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions in the bin folder, it just appears to be a different version than the one that is expected by this code.

I have tried to consolidate versions and update this package and dependent ones, to no avail.

What I am looking for specifically, is how to figure out what project/file/etc is expecting the specific version, and why.

As far as I can tell, everything in the entire solution appears to expect the correct version, yet something obviously doesn't.

The answer may be a Visual Studio option, an external tool (I have access to Resharper and other Jetbrains software), or a Nuget tool that I am not aware of. Anything that allows me to pinpoint what or who is expecting this erroneous version, so that I can then fix it, will qualify as a valid answer.

Comment: There's always `<bindingRedirect/>`. There should be enough information I'm the spew in the `Output` window during a _Rebuild All_ to give you some hintd

Comment: Which .NET version? .NET Framework is much more pedantic when it comes to resolving assembly redirects as .NET core.